# Break long text

Tags: javascript

I have a div which has width of say 200px. It does not show horizontal scroll bar. Now if anyone types any word more than 200px worth, it is simply hidden. I am wondering if its possible to automatically put a newline tag after every word reaches 200px length?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post your code. You can't type directly into a div (did you mean input area? Or is the div being populated through some script?)

Comment: div is being populated by a script, basically a chat program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achive this using simple CSS using

```
WORD-BREAK: break-ALL.

<div style="width: 200px; word-break: break-all">Content goes here</div>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for...

Comment: That's a non-standard MS extension to css. see http://www.htmlref.com/reference/appb/ms_extensions.htm

Comment: to be fair, it's also in the css3 spec, but like much of css3 support is inconsistent

Answer (score 3):

It's a tricky problem, but you should probably read http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html.

basically, there is somewhat inconsistent support and the linked article proposes use of:

```
wbr:after { content: "\00200B" }
```

in your css, and using the `<wbr/>` tag in your html

Answer (score 1):

There is a soft-hyphen that lets you define where a word can be broken up (For example, prod-uct-iv-ity) which doesn't display any hyphens, just defines where they could show up if the word has to wrap lines. It is entity &shy;

Answer (score 0):

If you have mono-spaced font, it'd be easy to count number of characters, and just insert a break-tag. But it's harder to calculate where to put in the break-tag with normal fonts.

For IE, you can set `word-break: break-all;` which will break words when they reach a certain length...

Answer (score 0):

word-break is good, but it is said not to work in firefox. (haven't tested.)

For firefox, use javascript.

It does work in webkit though.